# Enum outside class in Unity C#

Tags: c#, class, unity-game-engine, enums

I'm creating a script to manage the fading of UI elements in Unity3D, and at some point I'm stuck with enums

The other day I saw a very cool asset to fade elements, and decided to reverse engeneer it

After some time researching with tutorials and reading questions in this page, I got stuck using the enums, I don't know how to access my enum from another class so I want to ask for help

I'm using Unity version 5.3.5f1

**Goal**

- Fade UI elements in Unity (Images, buttons, etc)
- Fade via script
- Use of enums to do it
- Acces enums outside a class

**How to reproduce it**

- New Unity project (doesn't matter 2D or 3D)
- Empty gameobject
- UI element (image)
- Image fill screen and chance its color (any color)
- New C# script, I called it Test

**Done**

- Read about enums
- Basic class with enum

**Code C#**

Here's my code (so far)

```
using UnityEngine;
using UnityEngine.UI;

[System.Serializable]
public class FadeOperations
{
   public enum FadeManager
{
    fadeIn,
    fadeOut
};

  [Tooltip("Type of fading")]
  public FadeManager fadeType;

  [Tooltip("Duration time of the fading")]
  public float duration;

  [Tooltip("Select the image to fade")]
  public Image fadeImage;
}

public class Test : MonoBehaviour
{
  //Where do I acces the enum inside this class??

  //This is the variable for the inspector to see the elements inside the other class
  public FadeOperations[] fadeOperations;

  private void Start()
  {
  }
}
```

I'll be glad to read good explanations and noobfriendly answers

Thanks

Comment: First of all `FadeOperations` is a class. So you created array of objects. You can access your enum inside single object like this: `fadeOperations[0].fadeType` if array is not `null`.

Comment: You need to move enum FadeManager outside of the class block and than you will be able to access it

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Technically speaking, if you declare an enum inside a class, that enum acts as the nested class.

So, with the codebase you have at the moment, you would need to refer to FadeManager outside FadeOperations like here:

```
public class Test : MonoBehaviour
{
  // the variable of FadeManager type outside FadeOperations
  public FadeOperations.FadeManager fadeManager;

  public FadeOperations[] fadeOperations;

  private void Start()
  {
  }
}
```

However, you might find it more practical to move the enum outside the FadeOperations class instead:

```
public enum FadeManager
{
    fadeIn,
    fadeOut
};

[System.Serializable]
public class FadeOperations
{
    //FadeOperations body goes here...
}
```

Then you access the `FadeManager` class directly, by its name, in `FadeOperations` and other classes alike.

It's up to you to decide which works better for you.

Comment: This answer seem legit, will the enum behave like before??

Comment: Yup, it will behave the same in both cases, except in the first case you must refer to it as `FadeOperations.FadeManager` (when outside FadeOperations context) instead of just `FadeManager`.

Comment: I'll give it a try

Comment: Thanks it works like charm... but now I have a new problem, my code logic works halfway, the code only checks for 1 element of the enum, no matter if I use `switch` or `if` it only detects the first statement